# Prime Faces - Select Many Check Box with multiple Selected List

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to implement a select many check box. The source of list items are three different lists. I can handle the items to show in select list but the selected items also needs to be stored in three different Lists. How could we achieve this.

```
public class CheckBoxView {
    private List<String> asianNames, americanNames, africanNames;
    private List<String> selectedAsianNames, selectedAmericanNames, selectedAfricanNames;
}
```

Comment: This is currently not possible. it only supports one list and on your Server side you will have to break the selections into 3 lists based on your internal knowledge.

Comment: Ok Thank You. Do I delete this question or mark it answered ?

Comment: I think you can just leave it open for others to see.